# How to shade a plotted region in specific direction?

Tags: color, plotting, mathematical-optimization

I am using RegionPlot to plot a linear program

```
maximize 30x1+25x2
```

with the constraints

```
x1+x2 <= 10
x1 <= 6
x2 <= 9
5x1 + 2x2 <= 30
x1,x2 >= 0
```

Using the following command

```
RegionPlot[ x1 + x2 <= 10 && 
            x1 <= 6 &&
            x2 <= 9 &&
            x1 >= 0 &&
            x2 >= 0,
            {x1, 0,   10}, x2, 0, 10},
            ColorFunction -> Function[{x1, x2}, 30 x1 + 25 x2],
            ColorFunctionScaling -> True]
```

this is my result
 [image]

How can i change the color an scale it all over the region ? I tried `ColorFunctionScaling->True` but this does not change anything.

Comment: Please post the `RegionPlot[]` code as text. Thanks

Comment: Done, as requested :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a common misconception about what `ColorFunctionScaling ->` really does. It **DOESN'T** rescale the VALUES of the `ColorFunction[]` thingy, but the COORDINATES before feeding them into it.

Just look:

```
s = Reap@RegionPlot[x1 > x2, {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}, 
                   ColorFunction -> Function[{x1, x2}, Sow[x1 + x2]], 
                   ColorFunctionScaling -> #] & /@ {True, False};
{Min @ #, Max @ #} & /@ s[[All, 2]]
(* {{1.71127*10^-20, 2.}, {0.00205697, 19.9979}} *)
```

so:

```
ClearAll[x1, x2, col, const]; 

const = x1 + x2 <= 10 && 0 <= x1 <= 6 && 0 <= x2 <= 9 && 5 x1 + 2 x2 <= 30;
col[x1_, x2_] := 30 x1 + 25 x2
{min, max} = First /@ {Minimize @@ #, Maximize @@ #} &@{{col[x1, x2], const}, {x1, x2}};
RegionPlot[const, {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}, 
           ColorFunction -> Function[{x1, x2}, Rescale[col[x1,x2], {min, max}, {0, 1}]], 
           ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

You can scale the `ColorFunction` manually:

```
RegionPlot[
 x1 + x2 <= 10 && x1 <= 6 && x2 <= 9 && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0, {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x1, x2}, Rescale[30 x1 + 25 x2, {0, 300}, {0, 1}]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

[image]

Comment: ok, then i have to adjust the values until it looks good. I thought there would be an automatic option, that allows automatic scaling i.e. white is on (0,0), red is max value of 30x1+25x2

Answer (score 2):

```
RegionPlot[ x1 + x2 <= 10 && x1 <= 6 && x2 <= 9 && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0, {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10},
           ColorFunction -> ( (30 # + 25 #2)/(30 + 25) &)]
(* or ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, (30 x + 25 y)/(30 + 25)] *)
```

[image]

> white is on (0,0), red is max value of 30x1+25x2:

```
RegionPlot[x1 + x2 <= 10 && x1 <= 6 && x2 <= 9 && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0,
         {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10},
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Red}, (30 # + 25 #2)/55] &)]
```

[image]

```
Row[RegionPlot[x1 + x2 <= 10 && x1 <= 6 && x2 <= 9 && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0, 
              {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10},
              ColorFunction -> (#), PlotLabel -> Style[#, "Panel", 16]] & /@
     {RGBColor[0, 1, 0, (5 # + 50 #2)/55] &,
      RGBColor[1, 0, 0, (275 # + 275 #2)/550] &,
      RGBColor[0, 0, 1, (50 # + 5 #2)/55] &}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Row[RegionPlot[x1 + x2 <= 10 && x1 <= 6 && x2 <= 9 && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0,
              {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10},
              ColorFunction -> (#), PlotLabel -> Style[#, "Panel", 16]] & /@  
     {Blend[{White, Red}, (5 # + 50 #2)/55] &, 
      Blend[{White, Red}, (275 # + 275 #2)/550] &, 
      Blend[{White, Red}, (50 # + 5 #2)/55] &}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]