# Filling an area with cushion effect

Tags: filling

This code: (by @kguler, can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65519/how-to-shade-a-plotted-region-in-specific-direction/65529#65529), as an answer to "How to shade a plotted region in specific direction?")

```
Row[RegionPlot[x1 + x2 <= 10 && x1 <= 6 && x2 <= 9 && x1 >= 0 && x2 >= 0,
              {x1, 0, 10}, {x2, 0, 10},
              ColorFunction -> (#), PlotLabel -> Style[#, "Panel", 16]] & /@  
     {Blend[{White, Red}, (5 # + 50 #2)/55] &, 
      Blend[{White, Red}, (275 # + 275 #2)/550] &, 
      Blend[{White, Red}, (50 # + 5 #2)/55] &}, Spacer[5]]
```

will produce this:

[image]

However, I would like to produce filling of the area with some sort of cushion effect, like individual cells in following examples:

[image]

or:

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First attempt:

```
RegionPlot[1 == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Hue[1, 
     1 - Exp[-(Mod[#, 1.5, -0.5]^2 + Mod[#2, 1.5, -0.5]^2)], 1] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 120]
```

which produces this:

[image]

Second variation:

```
RegionPlot[1 == 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Piecewise[{{Hue[1, 
        1 - Exp[-12 (Mod[#1 + 0.6, 1.5, -0.5]^2 + 
             Mod[#2 + 0.6, 1.5, -0.5]^2)], 1], 
       Mod[#1 + 0.5, 1.5, -0.5]^2 + Mod[#2 + 0.5, 1.5, -0.5]^2 < 
        0.1}, {Hue[1, 
        1 - Exp[-(Mod[#1, 1.5, -0.5]^2 + Mod[#2, 1.5, -0.5]^2)], 1], 
       True}}] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 360]
```

which produces this:

[image]

This requires a disgustingly-large number of `PlotPoints`; hopefully someone knows a workaround. Incorporating antialiasing would be a plus. Here's an antialiased version produced using `Image`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to crop a `GaussianMatrix`:

```
f = GaussianMatrix[{{#1, #2}, Max[#1, #2]/2}][[#1 ;;, #2 ;;]] &
```

then

```
ColorNegate@(ArrayPlot@ArrayFlatten@ConstantArray[f[40, 40], {10, 10}])
```

[image: pillows]